# Vanilla SpringBoot app works in IntelliJ, but `mvn compile` fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, maven-compiler-plugin

When I create a vanilla SpringBoot app through the SpringBoot initializr option in IntelliJ, this creates a simple `DemoApplication.java` file:

```java
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
}
```

When I run `main` from IntelliJ it seems to work just fine (not that it does much right now):

```java
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)

2020-09-20 13:03:52.377  INFO 7456 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-5MKKIB9 with PID 7456 (C:\Users\jasonfil\code\demo\target\classes started by jasonfil in C:\Users\jasonfil\code\demo)
2020-09-20 13:03:52.377  INFO 7456 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-20 13:03:52.824  INFO 7456 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.75 seconds (JVM running for 1.446)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

but when I try to run `mvn compile` from the command line, I get a message about my compilation not being up to par:

```sh
C:\Users\jasonfil\code\demo>mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\jasonfil\code\demo\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.096 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-20T13:57:26-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

IntelliJ provided me with a basic `pom.xml`, and I have **not** touched it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am working in a project that needs Amazon's Java 11 Corretto JDK. Considering that the project builds and runs, I'm under the impression that the JDK is viewed just fine. I have also tried with Oracle's JDK 14, without luck. Here's the IntelliJ specification under `Project Structure`:

[image: Amazon Corretto JDK view from inside IntelliJ]

Lastly, seeing messages about `maven-compiler-plugin`, I also added

```xml
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

to my `pom`. No luck there either, after refreshing maven, cleaning and then compiling again. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried what described [here](https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/08/29/migrate-maven-projects-to-java-11-jigsaw/)? `release` properties and `Module Settings`

Comment: You have to set a JDK location via JAVA_HOME environment variable which the error `[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?` already stated. Apart from that giving a plugin as a dependency is simply wrong.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I should say, however, that [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.8.1) tends to disagree re:the plugin. They want it wrapped around a `<dependency>` pair of tags.